# Why does the Smooth scroll to element JavaScript always start on the top (mobile)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The Java Script that I'm using works fine. But on Mobiles it always starts on the top of the page and then scroll to the element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").on('click', function(event) {
        if (this.hash !== "") {
            event.preventDefault();
                var hash = this.hash;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 1200, function(){
                window.location.hash = hash;
            });
        }
    });
});
```